# What do I gain by including an i386 build when targeting Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, 32bit-64bit

I'm making a Mac OS X application that runs on Snow Leopard and later. At the moment the builds are fat and include separate i386 and x86_64 builds.

Is there any real point in doing this, or should I change to just including the x86_64 build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Early Intel Macs (from 2006) had Core Duo CPUs, which don't have a 64-bit mode at all. If you turn off the i386 architecture, Macs with those CPUs will no longer be supported by your app.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms what I suspected. Any idea what fraction of the Snow Leopard or Mac installed base this is? Obviously it's small but perhaps there are numbers somewhere.

Comment: Two different projects I've worked on record analytics about this. About a month ago, I saw 0.3% on one project (which requires 10.6.6), and 1.3% on another (which requires 10.5.0)—but under 0.01% for new installs. However, it's worth mentioning that the former is open source and the latter commercial, and that both allow the user to disable analytics, and that the former works fine without a network connection (in which case the analytics don't get recorded even if you've enabled them), so the 10.5 vs. 10.6 may not be the issue.